# puppet master not able to find configdir, how to fix this?

Tags: puppet

sudo puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize

When I ran above command

[root@puppetmaster bin]# sudo puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:1348:in `convert': Error converting value for param 'basemodulepath': Could not find value for $configdir (Puppet::Settings::InterpolationError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:1337:in`gsub'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:1337:in `convert'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:1315:in`interpolate'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:1060:in `value'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/settings.rb:121:in`[]'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet.rb:184:in `base_context'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:356:in`run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:146:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:92:in`execute'
        from /usr/bin/puppet:8

Even I created a environment variable now with $configdir with value /etc/puppet, but still same issue.

Please suggest how to rectify this

Answer (score 0):

Puppet does not ordinarily provide or rely on any "configdir" setting, but it does provide and rely on `confdir`.  Since Puppet is complaining about being able to determine the value of a different parameter, `basemodulepath`, I infer that,

1. You are using Puppet 3.8 with directory environments enabled (Ruby 1.8 is not supported in later versions, and `basemodulepath` is a directory environments thing), and
2. One of your environment.conf files erroneously specifies a value for its environment's `basemodulepath` in terms of `$configdir` instead of `$confdir`.

Note that Puppet 3.8 is obsolete and unsupported.  As I write this, the latest is Puppet 6.12.

Comment: I have updated the /etc/puppet/puppet.conf file now.

Comment: I am new to puppet and just started with plurasight videos. Can you suggest a good tutorial or documentation to start with.

Comment: Sorry, @UdayKiranReddy, we do not make recommendations for off-site resources here.